# Distrbute IOS apps without appstore?

Tags: ios

Here is my problem - there is hotel that has no connection to internet. It houses around 500-1000 during high season. I have local network that users can access, and where they can download my motel app for reservations / tours etc...

Since I don't have access to app store, i can't really put app there. My best guess would be enterprise program, so I can upload app on my local server, where every user can download it.

But is this even legal, since from all posts on SO, it seems apple intended something like this to be used only for testing, not actual deployment. Can I have some serious problems if I choose to distribute this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you can go with Apple Enterprise Program**

Here is what [Apple Enterprise Program License Agreement](https://download.developer.apple.com/Documentation/License_Agreements__Apple_Developer_Enterprise_Program/Apple_Developer_Enterprise_Program_License_Agreement_20170919.pdf) says about Deployment

> **6.2 Internal Use Applications used by Permitted Users and Customers**
>   
> You understand and agree that Apple reserves the right to review and approve or reject any
>   Internal Use Application that You would like to deploy for use by Your Customers (or that is
>   already in use by Your Customers) at any time during the Term of this Agreement as well as any
>   Internal Use Application that You would like to provide for use by Your Permitted Users. If
>   requested by Apple, You agree to fully cooperate with Apple and promptly provide such Internal
>   Use Application to Apple. You agree not to attempt to hide, misrepresent, mislead, or obscure
>   any features, content, services or functionality in Your submitted Internal Use Applications from
>   Apple's review or otherwise hinder Apple from being able to fully review such Applications.
>   
> You agree to inform Apple in writing if Your Internal Use Application connects to a physical
>   device, and You agree to cooperate with Apple and answer questions and provide information
>   and materials reasonably requested by Apple regarding such Internal Use Application. If You
>   make any changes to such Internal Use Application after such submission to Apple, You agree to
>   notify Apple and, if requested by Apple, resubmit such Internal Use Application prior to any
>   deployment of such modified Internal Use Application. Apple reserves the right to reject Your
>   Internal Use Application for deployment to Your Customers or Permitted Users for any reason
>   and at any time, even if Your Internal Use Application meets the Documentation and Program
>   Requirements; and, in that event, You agree that You may not deploy such Internal Use
>   Application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use enterprise for customers in this way. Check the latest Terms of Use but I quickly found this quote: `(2) deployment for use by Customers either on Your physical premises or under the direct supervision and physical control of Your Employees in other locations, subject to Apple’s right to review and approve such deployment as set forth herein.` Your customers would be using them on Your physical premises. One problem that you will have is creation, maintenance, and support. If you can get any internet connection at all, you should determine which is cheaper and better customer service, an internet connection and the app store or enterprise.